# Firefox-esr do not connect to local FTP server

Tags: firefox, debian, ftp

I'm learning twisted (python). After having started the FTP server on my Debian machine I tried to get (in the Firefox-esr browser) the list of the files. It had to be the list of files of "./", the dir where the server was started. In the browser address bar I entered

```
ftp://127.0.0.1:2121
```

and got just the list of Google results:

```
"Could not login to FTP, got this error on terminal. · Issue #3"
"FTP from command line not working?"
```

When I entered the local network address

```
ftp://192.168.1.15:2121
```

on MacBook in Safari address bar (High Sierra 10.13.6) I got redirected to Finder which after authentication showed the list of files in the './' remote directory (on the Debian machine).

How can I get the similar behavior on my Debian machine?

Using Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), python 3.9.2, Firefox-esr 115.3.1esr(64-bit)

**UPDATE 10/11/23**

```
$ lynx ftp://127.0.0.1:2121
```

or

```
$ ftp localhost 2121
```

gets me the list of the directory './'

Comment: Browsers no longer support the FTP protocol. Use an FTP client instead.

Comment: @DanielB I thought so. I remember I was using the feature before.